# Passing string field value to another field in same Feature Class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

All the literature I have read suggests that to pass a string value to a another field in a feature class via ArcPy you need to do the following. I am running it in ArcMap 10.6.

`arcpy.CalculateField_management(New_Labels_layer, "FC_Field", "'Word_Variable'", "VB", "")` will pass a word variable. While it successfully runs it does not pass the variable into the field. I did an exist function. So I know it exists and is being identified. The field I want to pass to is a string field.

`arcpy.CalculateField_management(New_Labels_layer, "Area", Numeric_Variable, "VB", "")`
successfully passes a numeric variable.

I have tried the following variations:

- `'Word_Variable'`
- `"Word_Variable"`
- `"'%Word_Variable%'"`
- `"%Word_Variable%"`
- `!Word_Variable!`

None of these seems to work. Most allow me to run the script but do not pass anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the syntax for the `arcpy.CalculateField()` function:

`CalculateField_management(in_table, field, expression, {expression_type}, {code_block})`

In the `expression` parameter you have to pass a string referencing a field. However, the way you reference another field will depend on the `expression_type`. In your code you are specifying `VB`. In the [tool's documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm) is stated that:

> For VB calculations, field names must be enclosed in square brackets (`[fieldname]`).

In case you want to pass a Python expression you have to specify `'PYTHON'` as your `expression_type`. Furthermore:

> For Python calculations, field names must be enclosed in exclamation points (`!fieldname!`).

None of your examples would work by passing a `VB` expression. however, your last example should work if you change the `expression_type` to `'PYTHON'`.

Comment: `# Process: Calculate Field
arcpy.CalculateField_management(New_Labels_layer, "Area", !Word_Variable!, "VB", "")` give me the following error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents\Type_SelectV1.py", line 208, in <module>
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(New_Labels_layer, "Area", [Word_Variable], 'VB', "")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3654, in CalculateField
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool

Failed to execute (TypeSelections).`

Comment: `# Process: Calculate Field arcpy.CalculateField_management(New_Labels_layer, "Area", [Word_Variable], "PYTHON", "")` give me the following error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax (Type_SelectV1.py, line 208) Failed to execute (TypeSelections).`

Comment: Yeah, you are mixing it up. For `'PYTHON'` use `'!Word_Variable!'`, for `'VB'` use `'[Word_Variable]'`

Comment: Furthemore, make sure you are passing a string. If you pass `[Word_Variable]` Python will interpret it a list.

Comment: I tried it every possible combination thereof. It will not allow me to produce a string, variable or not. I can have a numeric value pass into the field but that same field wouldn't accept a text value or variable. I triple checked that it was a text field.

Comment: It is working fine for me. The only thing that occurs to me is that you declared `Word_Variable` somewhere in your script and it is a string. If the field you are trying to calculate is called `Area` and your text field is called `my_field` the code would be as follows: `arcpy.CalculateField_management(New_Labels_Layer, 'Area', '!my_field!', 'PYTHON')`

Comment: thank you for your patience. With your help and the below solution I figured it out, `https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56665/debugging-error-000539-from-calculatefield-in-arcpy`

Answer (score 1):

When you put the name of your variable into quotes, you are essentially just passing the name of the variable as a string. What you want to do is pass the variable itself, as it is a reference to a string.

Do it just like you do for the numeric variable and pass the variable name without quotes and it should work as expected.

`arcpy.CalculateField_management(New_Labels_layer, "FC_Field", Word_Variable, "VB", "")`